# How to scope a provider in riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod, flutter-state

I'm starting to use [`riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) and I'm trying to migrate my existing code which was using [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

With `provider`, the `Provider`s were scoped in the widget tree. Only the children of the `Provider` widget could access its model.

It says in the `riverpod`'s doc:

> Allows easily accessing that state in multiple locations. Providers are a complete replacement for patterns like Singletons, Service Locators, Dependency Injection or InheritedWidgets.
>
> * "*Providers"* here refers to the `Provider` class of the package `riverpod`.

And the `provider` package was a simplification/wrapper/API around `InheritedWidget`s so I guess what was possible with `provider` is also possible with `riverpod`.

But I cannot manage to find out how to do it.

---

Here is a small example of what I am trying to migrate.

```dart
class Counter extends ValueNotifier<int> {
  Counter(): super(0);
}


class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
      create: (_) => Counter();
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  context.read<Counter>().value++;
                }, 
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
              Text('Count: ${context.watch<Counter>().value}'),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Wherever there is a `MyWidget` widget, the sub-widget has access to a unique/scoped model `Counter`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scoping providers is done through `ProviderScope`

You can do:

```dart
final provider = ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());


// in some widget:

return ProviderScope(
  overrides: [
    provider.overrideWithProvider(
      ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => Counter());
    ),
  ],
)
```

Although if you can avoid scoping, do so. Scoping providers is generally not recommended and should be avoided as that's fairly advanced.

If you're using a scoped provider so that the state is destroyed when the user leaves the page, a much simpler solution is to use `autoDispose`:

```dart
final provider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose<Counter>((ref) => Counter());

// No longer needed to scope the provider
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it out. The reason I want to scope the providers is that I might have several times the same pages in my history that need a different instance of the `ChangeNotifier`. For example, I could have several pages of `UserDetails` about different users, so I cannot share the same instance of `ChangeNotifier`. But the pages are still there in the history. That's why I don't think simply using ` autoDispose` will make it work

Comment: Maybe you want `family` then.

Comment: Yes, I think that would work for the `UserDetails` example. Now if there is no id, would this still work? For example, a page that could be `UsersList` and has no parameter. The provider could contain filters apply by the user after the page is built. And you could have several instances of `UsersList` in the history that should not share the same provider.

Comment: You could make an enum corresponding to the page that is trying to read the list.

Comment: I don't think that would work, the page is really the same one. It happens when the users goes twice to the same page and therefore, the same page is twice there in the history.

Comment: Quick Q here, in the case of having a Provider used on 2 pages, one implements the AutomaticKeepAlive mixin then you navigate(push) to the second one which doesn't. In this case, is the auto dispose triggered? Or should provider scope be used here?

Answer (score 0):

Inside ProviderScope is an InheritedWidget, so you can you multiple ProviderScope just like Provider. Please checkout the code of Remi in this ticket [link](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/1174).

Or you can use .family and .autoDispose for your purpose.